# Proof of inverse substitution for integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand that integration by direct substitution works because of the chain rule for derivatives, that is if $F' = f$, and $u=g(x)$ then

$$ \int f(g(x))g'(x)dx = \int f(u)du = F(u) = F(g(x))$$

But for inverse substitution where we let $x=g^{-1}(u)$, thus $dx=(g^{-1})'(u)du$, and then substitute:

$$ \int f(g(x))dx = \int f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)du\label{eq_1}\tag{1}$$

I don't understand why this is a valid transformation, I consulted Spivak calculus and here is his proof:

$$\int f(g(x))dx = \int f(g(x))\cdot g'(x)\cdot\frac{1}{g'(x)}dx = \int f(u)\cdot \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(u))}du\label{eq_2}\tag{2}$$

And $\eqref{eq_1}$ and $\eqref{eq_2}$ are identical since $$(g^{-1})'(u) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(u))} $$ QED.

I don't understand why the transformation in $\eqref{eq_2}$ is valid, any help regarding this?

**Edit**

I don't understand why the transformation in $\eqref{eq_2}$
is valid, since it is not in the format of the chain rule(as per my understanding) in the beginning of the post

**Edit 2**:

Okay, so it seems indeed that the inverse substitution needs justification that is more involved than simply applying the chain rule once, in the light of [Teaching Integration by Substitution by Gale](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/0002989009124.di991793.99p00304.pdf) I came with the following proof:

**Theorem**: Assume we have functions $f$ and $g$, let $w=f.(g^{-1})'$, then if $W'=w$, then $$(W \circ g)' = f \circ g$$

Proof:
$$(W \circ g)'= (W' \circ g).g' = (w \circ g).g'$$
$$=((f.(g^{-1})') \circ g).g' = (f \circ g).((g^{-1})' \circ g).g'$$
$$= (f \circ g).(\frac{1}{g' \circ g^{-1}}\circ g).g' = (f \circ g).(\frac{1}{g'}).g' = f \circ g$$

Can someone come with a simpler proof? I think this can be proved as a special case of the inverse substitution mentioned in the by Gale

**Edit 3**

Indeed this is just a special case of the general case proved by Gale, which states that with the substitution $x=g(t)$ we have:

$$ \int f(x)dx = \int f(g(t)) g'(t)dt \label{eq_3}\tag{3}$$.

In the indefinite integral $$ \int f(g(x))dx $$

Let $x = g^{-1}(u)$, substituting in $\eqref{eq_3}$ we have
$$ \int f(g(x))dx = \int f(g(g^{-1}(u)))(g^{-1})'(u)du = \int f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)du$$ as desired

Comment: What is it you don't think is valid about it? Also a slight remark: you forgot the integration constant, which *is* important

Comment: The transformation (2) is valid because it is a result of the substitution $u=g(x)$.

Comment: I added an edit: I  don't understand why the transformation in (2) is valid, since it is not in the format of the chain rule(as per my understanding) in the beginning of the post

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you can work this way, let $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ invertible function as you require, $g(x) = u$ so $x=g^{-1}(u)$ and let $h=g^{-1}$. We want to evaluate
$$I:=\int f(g(x))dx$$
How this integral is expressed in terms of $u$ as above we have
$$g(x) = u \iff x= g^{-1}(u) \\
x= h(u) \implies dx = h'(u)du$$
And now
$$I = \int f(u)h'(u)du = \int f(u)(g^{-1})(u)du$$
exactly what we need. Hope this helps!

---

For the Spivak's proof we have to remember that since
$$g(x) = u\implies g'(x)dx = du\\
x= g^{-1}(u)$$
If you make all of this substitution in
$$\int f(g(x)) \cdot \color{red}{g'(x)}\cdot \frac{1}{g'(x)}\color{red}{dx} = \int f(u) \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(u)}\color{red}{du}$$

---

PS I'm omitting integrationn constant (as pointed out are important) feel free to fill the missing gaps ;-).

Comment: I don't see how this follows from the chain rule, since it is not in the format of the chain rule